# Clicking UI element with JXA doesn't work

Tags: javascript, automation, applescript, ui-automation, javascript-automation

I'm trying to interact with the default Mail app using Javascript for Automation (JXA). I want to click on the first email in the list so that it opens in its own window. but clicking does nothing. The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081723/how-to-click-ui-element-using-jxa) is what I tried and it does not work.

[image]

My code:

```
var se = Application("System Events");
var mail = se.applicationProcesses.byName("Mail");

mail.windows[0]
.splitterGroups[0]
.splitterGroups[0]
.groups[0]
.scrollAreas[0]
.tables[0]
.rows[0].click()
```

If I remove the `click()` and use `.select()` it will select the email from the menu, but clicking on the email list item itself just returns `null` in the repl. I tried clicking on each of the inner `uiElements` but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an AppleScript that shows how to open a message in a new window.
You should be able to readily translate that to JXA.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/390549/915019

It is better to use the app's object model than UI scripting.

Comment: Thanks your link helped in opening the actual email. However for some things UI Scripting is necessary, and I still would like to understand why clicking on the selected email does nothing? There are other apps without proper object models that I would like to automate.

Comment: @Rup Because on this table, you need to double click on a row to open the message in the new window. Generally the click command works when an `ui element` contains the "**AXPress**" action (the rows of this table in the window of the **Mail** application have no actions).